# Can I make an ajax response cross-domain?

Tags: ajax, security

I am trying to make a single ajax response cross-domain. Is that possible? I tried something like this, but that did not work:

```
function my_call_callback() {
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  if (headers_sent())
      echo "headers was sent";
  else
      echo "headers was not sent"; // This is what I get
  die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_call', 'my_call_callback');
```

UPDATE: It suddenly started working. No idea why. I suspect some problem with the web hotel I am using since I just told about an attach attempt I noticed. They told me to block the attackers IP in .htaccess. Perhaps they did some review of the .htaccess files. I really have no idea though.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have zero output before setting that header? See http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html for refernce

Comment: Good question, @codearachnid. I have been trying to find a way to check that, but I have no idea how to do it. I can check the output in Wordpress there by just using "die()", but how do I know if the empty line after the headers has been sent?

Comment: Define "didn't work"? Does header not get applied? Does header not lead to expected results in practice?

Comment: Hm, another good question ;-)
Thanks, @Rarst. When looking at the response headers in Firebug I can't see any Access-Control-Allow-Origin. And I get an error saying that there was no such header.

Comment: And when doing this request from the wordpress site I can see there is nothing in the XHR responseText before my echo in the code above.

Comment: I added a check to the code above. Headers have not been sent before my call to "echo". So it is something else that prevents the header to be sent.

Comment: I opened a new question on stackoverflow since that might be more appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648258/why-is-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-not-sent